# How do I create an .exe (or similar) for a VS15 VB.net website?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2015

I was asked by my client to build a basic website in Visual Studios 2015 that allows them to view mapping relationships between data. The entire thing is fully functional and tested. It is connected to a local MS Access database since it only needs to be a basic intro product.

The issue I am having is that the client requested the application as a .exe file so they can take it throughout the company and raise more funding for the project. I can't seem to find any options to build the program as an .exe or anything similar to that. VS15 seems to only want me to use Azure, which we do not have the funding to purchase. The solution to this does not need to be pretty, but it does need to be functional and portable. I developed the program on a PC, but the client has a Mac and wants to use that for the demos.

What do I need to do in order to give the client what they want without having to purchase something else or as for a server to run the website on? Is there any way I can allow the client to use the application without needing to run the entire program?

Please feel free to ask for any additional detail, as needed.

Thanks for your help!

-WS

Comment: That's not how websites work.  You need a server.

Comment: Or you could write your own EXE that serves the ASP.Net site from an in-process HTTP server (this would be much easier on .Net Core).

Comment: Do you mean you want to build an installer package that installs the web site?  InstallShield is a good way to do that, although there are several cheaper or even free solutions.  I've used the Nullsoft installer on a project.  I think it's still available even though Nullsoft went out of business years ago.

Comment: So we initially thought it would be built out as a website, but that changed and now we have to figure out a way to provide this website and the functionality locally. I know this language from college and was not expecting to be alone on how to figure out how to publish the solution. How would I go about the 2 options that don't require a server?

Comment: google "self hosting ASP.NET site"  :)

Comment: Isn't the self hosting essentially what the debug is doing? I want to be able to provide the client with a wrapped solution that can be ran from anywhere, without the need to have visual studios installed. I am just nervous that because it is coded as a website, I need a server no matter what...

Comment: The server can be your own process.  A self-hosting site does not need VS.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are correct - that's not exactly how this works.  When you're hitting "play" in Visual Studio, it's using IIS Express by default: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5(v=vs.120).aspx

Your best bet will be to use that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview

However that is only for the "web server" part - you'll still need to deploy your application like you would another asp.net project - it will not be an executable though, it'll be served up as compiled html / js files and vb, etc

Once you have IIS express setup and running, you'll be able to hit that website like you do when debugging (http://localhost:SOMEPORT)